# meaning of "not as common"

Tags: meaning

A teach in an English lesson gives this example

> "I went to the store"

and then explains

> whenever you have a movement, and you have a destination... So by movement I mean: "go", "walk", "drive",
>   "take the bus", for example. Anything that involves you moving or going somewhere and
>   then you're talking about the destination, - means the place that you are going to -, it's
>   always going to be "to". And this is very much a preposition showing direction. Okay?
>   Now, there are of course exceptions. There are situations where you can use "for". "Head
>   for the hills", "Make for the lobby", okay? But very, very specific situations, very specific
>   verbs and you're not going to use them that often because they're **not as common**.

where the phrase "not as common" is used.

I found [lots of people also use "not as common"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22not%20as%20common%22), and some of those are "not as common **as**"

I googled "not as common" and got "it's seen around but not a lot", which is good explanation though, I still cannot get a clear understanding.

If I substitute the following for "not as common", do the sentences mean the same?

1. not very common
2. not so common
3. not too much common

Comment: The teacher is saying that using _for_ when speaking of going to a place is not as common as using _to_ . It's a _comparative_. Your sentences are not comparatives (and we would never say   _not too much common_)

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. I guess I've learned it. "not as common" is a comparative adjective phrase, is my understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that it's not as common as something else mentioned before.

The fact that **(something) is very common** is established first by saying for example : You can see it anywhere , it's widely available...etc then something else in same category is mentioned that's less commonly used/observed/encountered/known.

You can think of it this way :

**(the thing I have just mentioned is)** not as common **(as the thing I previously mentioned )**