# "I've learned it" or "I learned it"?

Tags: word-usage

In my other post ([What does "not as common" mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239962/109190)) I said

> I guess I've learned it.

Actually I am not sure if I used the right tense.

I was trying to express the following

> I didn't understand that before read the comment. After read the comment, I understood. I got what the answerer is trying to let me know. Based on what I got just now, I am going to state something more.

To convey the meaning above, should I use

> I've learned it.

or

> I learned it.

Are there other better expressions for this situations?

Comment: It's not directly related to your question but notice that after a preposition usually goes a gerund https://www.grammaring.com/preposition-gerund "before read the comment" should be "before reading the comment", And the same applies to "after read". And it should be "other post" instead of "another post"  because you haven't mentioned other post before. another = used to refer to an additional person or thing of the same type as one already mentioned. No post has been mentioned before your "another post".

Comment: You can always say **I've got it** or even shorter **I got it**. Those are two of the most common ways to let somebody know that you understood what they were explaining to you. But keep in mind that those expressions are a little bit more informal.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin Thank you. I got it. I have been guessing which tense should I use in this kind of situations, past simple or present perfect.